# Magento 2 : How to change the attributes that manage the stock?

Tags: magento2, module, product-attribute, products

I'd like to change the attributes **inventory_manage_stock** and **manage_stock** for a product by ID.

I'm using a custom module, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Can specify your requirement in detail, what you need to do with this.

Comment: I've changed the description @DhirenVasoya, thanks